# Set the default value in the sharedPreferences according to the value in the other activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities (MainActivity and MapActivity). The both have icon in the menu to stop and start the background tracking service. Concerning the usere's choice the image of the button's icon will change. I am using the sharedPrefernces to store the boolean value of the `serviceStatus` to set the right image for the icon but I am facing problem when I go from the MainActivity-->MapActivity and stop the background tracking service in the MapActivity I am always getting the `on` icon image in the menu of the MainActivity. I think it is because of the true default value in this line `(mSharedPreference.getBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", true));` in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

How can I set it for this first time as ture and later according to the user's action in the MapActivity? Also if the user stops the service in the MapActivity then the value should be `false` and not always true.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle);

    final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    serviceStatus = (mSharedPreference.getBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", true));
    editor = mSharedPreference.edit();
    editor.apply();

    if (serviceStatus) {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.on);

    } else {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.off);

    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**MapActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    markerMap.clear();

    stopAlarm();

    if (serviceStatus) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", serviceStatus);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the service status to true or false depending on the status. I think currently you are setting only for true

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  markerMap.clear();
  stopAlarm();

  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", serviceStatus);
  editor.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below MapActivity code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//super.onBackPressed();
markerMap.clear();

stopAlarm();

if (serviceStatus) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sharedServiceStatus", serviceStatus);
    editor.commit();
}
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

code after `super.onBackPressed();` will not execute i think..